# Git errors when trying to add, commit, push with symlinked folder

Tags: git

I have a local directory I cloned with a remote. However, when I try add, commit, push to the remote server, I get the following.

Any help appreciated please.

```
$ git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .meteor/.finished-upgraders.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .meteor/.gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .meteor/.id.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .meteor/packages.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .meteor/platforms.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .meteor/release.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .meteor/versions.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
error: readlink("node_modules"): Function not implemented
error: unable to index file node_modules
fatal: adding files failed
```

Then:

```
$ git commit -a -m "commit"

On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
        .gitignore
        .meteor/
        node_modules
        server/
        tsconfig.json
        tslint.json
        typings

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

Then:

```
$ git push
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/remote-thewhozoo.git'
```

Also when I:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://git.heroku.com/remote-thewhozoo.git
  Push  URL: https://git.heroku.com/remote-thewhozoo.git
  HEAD branch: (unknown)
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
```

As you can see, I have symbolic links.

[image]

Comment: What is there in `.gitignore` file ?

Comment: `.gitignore` has `node_modules/`

Comment: Did you add `node_modules/` in `.gitignore` file recently ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem already occurs when you try to add files:

```
error: readlink("node_modules"): Function not implemented
error: unable to index file node_modules
fatal: adding files failed
```

One solution would be to add your *untracked* files explicitly instead of adding them all at once and skipping `node_modules`. That would enable you to commit and push your changes. But I think this wouldn't solve your problem in the long run.

The error message indicates, that `node_modules` is a symbolic link (symlink). So you have two options: If you dont need to version that folder, you may add it to your `.gitignore` by adding `/node_modules`. If you have to track it, you can do this by setting the `core.symlink` to `true`:

```
git config core.symlinks true
```

In either case you will be able to run `git add .` without getting any errors.

Comment: You are correct, I do have symbolic links. I'm amazed you knew that.  I have added that to the main question. I will try `git config core.symlinks true`. Thanks!

Comment: Seems a horrible practice to add your node_modules to git.  Double horrible because you symlink it.